# How to make tri angle with blank inside using c++?

Tags: c++

I did try many modifications to my code to make like this, but i not get what i want :

example if i put 7 in variable N the result will show

```
*
**
* *
*  *
*   *
*    *
*******
```

this my code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()  {
    for (int x=1; x<=N; x++){
        cout<<"*";
        for (int y=1; y<x; y++){
            cout<<"*";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

what i must add to my code have to the result like above?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`). Learn to use a debugger (`gdb`). Use also `std::endl` and `std::fflush`; your code never outputs any space.

Comment: looks like homework? :/

Comment: @basileStarynkevitch i must study c++ without using namespace std? mmm okey

Comment: @MarsonMao No no, i am only study looping case in c++. yes i am study programming in my school but this is not homework. I know someday i will get homework to build a program with loop statement, so i study from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since others have suggested that this might be homework, here are some tips:

- Always make sure you have a [valid main signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c). `int main()` is sufficient and `main()` without a return type is invalid.
- Enable warnings. `-Wall -pedantic` should be sufficient for most cases (i.e, it catches the above mistake) but `-Wextra` can be useful as well.
- [using namespace std;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) is considered bad practice because you may define functions or variable names that clash with imported names. Get into the habit of typing `std::`. (For example, an assignment may require you to have a `distance` function, which may conflict with [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).
- Use descriptive variable names. For a trivial program, `x`, `y` and `N` are fine, but decrease readability. It also helps you visualize the problem you are trying to solve.

We know that `y` is always going to be at most `x` because the number of characters per line should equal the current line. For example, line 7 should contain 7 asterisks. We only print a space if `y` is not equal to zero or `x - 1`, because that should be our "border". Lastly, the final line should contain all asterisks.

```
// The amount of asterisks per line is [1, N]
for (int x = 1; x <= N; x++)
{
    // x is the amount of characters we want to print per line
    for (int y = 0; y < x; y++)
    {
        // If we at the beginning or end of a line, this is our "border".
        // Print an asterisk.
        if (y == 0 || (y + 1 == x))
            std::cout << "*";
        else
        {
            // Otherwise we are "inside" the triangle.
            // If this is the last line, print all asterisks
            if (x == N)
                std::cout << "*";
            else
                std::cout << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Also, as another answer suggested, you can eliminate the need for confusing `if` structures by putting your condition into a single variable.

```
bool space_or_asterisk = (y == 0 || (y + 1 == x) || x == N);
std::cout << (space_or_asterisk ? '*' : ' ');
```

Comment: haha yeah i am forget to type int, okey next i should try to enable warnings. thank you for your information. My logic is still too weak, i must study looping case by hard. before i asked it on this forum, i tried to eliniminate y variable using if and i tried looking for escort and tutorial in google but the result not looks like my hope.

Comment: before i asked it on this forum, i tried to eliniminate y variable using if and i tried looking for escort and tutorial in google but the result not looks like my hope.

Answer (score 2):

While you've gotten a couple of answers that work, the logic can be quite a bit simpler if you eliminate the confusing `if`/`then`/`else` statements:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    static const char chars[] = "* ";
    static const int size = 7;

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<size; j++)
            std::cout << chars[j!=0 && i!=j && bool(i+1-size)];
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Although the logic is clearly simpler, you still want to be sure to study it enough to answer any questions about it if you turn this in as homework.

Comment: yeahhh i must study hard have to i can solve my poblem by myselft. Thank you for your suggestion. my problem only how to eleminate condition using if-then-else. right sir ?

Comment: @AgiMaulana: Well, you can either use an if-then-else, or else you can use other logic to eliminate it, but you need to do something to print out spaces in the middle and asterisks at the beginning and end of each line (and across the whole bottom line).

Comment: can you give me a task? to train my logic. from simple task to medium expert task

Answer (score 0):

```
main()  {
    for (int x=1; x<=N; x++){
        for (int y=1; y<=x; y++){
           if(y==1||y==x||x==N){
              cout<<"*";
           }else{
              cout<<"*";
           }
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```